# PEG Online Judge Coding

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I am solving a problem on the PEG Online Judge, which is a site where you can solve lots of problems for practice and fun.

I am having trouble with one in particular.  I have posted there for help but am not receiving any.

It is the Caporegime problem: http://wcipeg.com/problem/capos

You can use a number of languages to solve this.  I decided on Python (although I have coded it in C++ too).  There are 12 datasets the judge uses in testing the code.  My code passes 11/12.  I have no idea why I can't pass the last test and am hoping someone can help me.

I think it's a set partitioning problem of some kind and I solve it with a breadth first search approach.  The problem datasets are not big, so it doesn't get out of hand.

Here is my solution:

```
import sys
import copy

class SearchState():
    def __init__(self, label, crews):
        self.label = label
        self.crews = crews

    def __repr__(self):
        return "State: %s: %s" % (self.label, str(self.crews))


def crewsSoldierCanBeIn(s, crews, grudges):
    '''
      For a given soldier and a list of crews and grudges,
      return the crews the soldier an go in
    '''

    noGrudgeCrews = []
    for i, crew in enumerate(crews):
        conflict = False
        for c in crew:
            if [s, c] in grudges or [c, s] in grudges:
                conflict = True
                break
        if not conflict:
            noGrudgeCrews.append(i)

    return noGrudgeCrews    


def solve(numSoldiers, grudges):
    '''
      Put each soldier in a crew, output min no. of crews and who is in them
    '''

    crews = [[1]]
    numStates = 0
    states = [SearchState(numStates, crews)]

    for s in range(2, numSoldiers+1):
        newStates = []
        for state in states:
            possibleCrews = crewsSoldierCanBeIn(s, state.crews, grudges)
            if len(possibleCrews) > 0:
                for crew in possibleCrews:
                    numStates += 1
                    newCrews = copy.deepcopy(state.crews)
                    newCrews[crew].append(s)
                    newStates.append(SearchState(numStates, newCrews))
            else:
                numStates += 1
                newCrews = copy.deepcopy(state.crews)
                newCrews.append([s])
                newStates.append(SearchState(numStates, newCrews))

        states = copy.deepcopy(newStates)


    minNumCrews = 1000000
    minState = -1
    for i, state in enumerate(states):
        if len(state.crews) < minNumCrews:
            minNumCrews = len(state.crews)
            minState = i


    print(len(states[minState].crews))
    for crew in states[minState].crews:
        for s in crew:
            print("%d " % (s),  end = "")
        print()

def readInData(f):

    numSoldiers, numGrudges = map(int, f.readline().strip().split())
    grudges = []
    for _ in range(numGrudges):
        grudges.append(list(map(int, f.readline().strip().split())))

    return numSoldiers, grudges


def main():

    # Read in the data
    f = sys.stdin

    numSoldiers, grudges = readInData(f)

    solve(numSoldiers, grudges)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is a question and answer site. What's your question? Be specific.

Comment: Your question doesn't really show effort to make it answerable. An explanation of your general algorithm would be helpful. Why should your code work? What reason do you have to think that your algorithm is right?

Comment: Hmmm OK, not sure how I can explain it more fully.  You'd have to be interested to read the problem statement at the link I gave.  So that fully describes the problem.  I then went on to say it's a set partitioning problem, and I'm using a breadth first search algorithm to try and find the minimum no. of sets.  I can write pages and pages on this stuff I guess, but assumed people would want a short, concise entry?

Comment: So my question is "Why can't I get the right answer for all of the datasets the online judge uses?"  I must have an error somewhere, or not be thinking of certain test cases.

Comment: So this code fails on the last test. I can't see that test (this is the way the online judge works), so I can't tell what the data is nor why my code fails on that particular set of data.

Comment: You're not considering all possible neighbor states.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks.  Just enough of a hint to help me without giving the answer.  I'll work on this idea.

Comment: Well I've worked on this solidly for 2 days and can't solve it.  I tried various rewrites.  I've done it from the other way around i.e. start with all the soldiers in the state, and then apply each grudge constraint, but whichever way I do it, it's either too slow or uses too much memory for the grader.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I've finally solved this.

Basically I needed to use a DFS approach, it can't really be solved (withing the online Judge's memory and time constraints) via BFS.

The advantage of DFS is twofold: 1) I can reach a solution (not the best solution) fairly quickly and use this to prune the tree, to get rid of heaps of partial solutions that will never be any good and 2) Very little memory is needed.

So DFS is faster and uses less memory, for this problem.